# Arraylist prints the addres of the elements

Tags: java

this code prints the address like this --> project.Cateogry@d038117

```
Cate=c.listCat();
Arrays.toString(Cate.toArray());
```

what is wrong ?!!!! i want to print the elements from the arraylist "Cate"

Comment: @John3136 The OP is already using `Arrays.toString()`, the problem is that the Category class doesn't override `toString()`.

Comment: It would be nice if you added your `Cate` class code

Answer (score 0):

Let's check the javadoc of `toArray`,

> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this list in proper
>   sequence (from first to last element).
>
> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are
>   maintained by this list. (In other words, this method must allocate a
>   new array even if this list is backed by an array). The caller is thus
>   free to modify the returned array.

As you can see, the return value of it is a java array, if you want to print the content inside the array, there are multiple ways in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array) mentioned in the comment.

Btw, if you're interested about why path@hashcode is printed, please refer to this thread [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)